# Prove that the map $F:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$, $F(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ is $C^\infty$.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

[image]

[image]

Why isn't smoothness of $(\cos t,\sin t)$ as a map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ enough? IS it because when we have $S^1$, the codomain is changed? But that shouldn't affect smoothness, right? Why do we need to bring in charts to prove smoothness?

Comment: You first have to define the differentiable structure on $S^2$ by choosing smooth charts. (which makes the exercise become circular reasoning in a way)

Comment: But being a subset of R^2 , doesn't it inherit the differentiable structure of R^2?

Comment: I think the canonical "smooth submanifold differentiable structure" could be the one defined by the charts you get from implicit function theorem (if your manifold is the zero set of a smooth function which is true for the sphere i think this is reasonable). This is a comment, no answer. just my thoughts about the topic^^.